# Laravel Dynamic Navbar from Database

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

**Changed the source code so it now works properly.**

I created a dynamic navigation for the frontend page. However, I had a little problem with it. When I navigate to the page of one of the entries in the blog menu item (for example: 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/one-post), I move the mouse over any of my menu items in the navigation bar, and the paths of all my menu items receive the /blog prefix.

The content parts are attached to the pages, so I can add more content elements to each page on the administration page.

So, normally I have these routes:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/history
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact

If I visit a blog post (localhost/laravelprojekt/blog/one-post), the url link of each menu item will be this if I move the mouse over the menu items:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/home
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blog
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/about
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/history
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/contact

My codes are:

routes\web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'blog'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts.index');
    Route::get('/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('posts.show');
});

Route::get('/', HomeController::class)->name('home');
Route::get('/contact', [HomeController::class, 'contact'])->name('pages.contact');
Route::get('/{slug}', [HomeController::class, 'show'])->name('pages.show');
```

App\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {        
        $featuredPosts = Post::published()->featured()->with('categories')->latest('published_at')->take(4)->get();

        $latestPosts = Post::published()->with('categories')->latest('published_at')->take(12)->get();

        $page = self::pageData('home');

        return view('home', [
            'featuredPosts' => $featuredPosts,
            'latestPosts' => $latestPosts,
            'page' => $page,
        ]);
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        $page = self::pageData('contact');

        return view('pages.show-contact', [
            'page' => $page,
        ]);
    }

    public static function show($slug)
    {
        $page = self::pageData($slug);

        if($page->slug == "home")
        {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return view('pages.show', [
            'page' => $page,
        ]);
    }

    public static function pageData($slug)
    {
        abort_unless($page = Page::whereSlug($slug)->first(), 404);

        return $page;
    }
}
```

App\Http\Controllers\PostController.php

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
           $query->published();
        })->take(10)->get();

        $page = self::pageData('blog');

        return view(
            'posts.index',
            [
                'categories' => $categories,
                'page' => $page,
            ]
        );
    }

    public function show($slug)
    {
        abort_unless($post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->first(), 404);

        return view(
            'posts.show',
            [
                'post' => $post
            ]
        );
    }

    public static function pageData($slug)
    {
        abort_unless($page = Page::whereSlug($slug)->first(), 404);

        return $page;
    }
}
```

resources\views\components\menu.blade.php

```
@foreach ($menu as $item)
    <li>
        <a href="/{{ $item->slug }}" class="inline-flex items-center hover:text-yellow-900 text-sm text-gray-500">
            {{ $item->name }}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Specifying the / sign within the  parameter or in the page database slug field.

Thanks for the help [brombeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8034901/brombeer)

Comment: Set up vhosts for your webserver or use `php artisan serve` to serve your projects. How do you assemble the links in your nav?

Answer (score -1):

The server is of course running (php artisan serve).

The menu is structured as follows:

resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php

```
@foreach ($menu as $item)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ $item->slug }}" class="inline-flex items-center hover:text-yellow-900 text-sm text-gray-500">
            {{ $item->name }}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is not really an _answer_ to your question. Please edit your question and post relevant information there. Thanks

Comment: "_The server is of course running (php artisan serve)._" That is strange, since your urls are `localhost/laravelprojekt`. If you had `php artisan serve` running, from your project folder (assuming `laravelprojekt` is your project folder) your urls should be `http://localhost:8000/home`, `http://localhost:8000/blog` etc

Comment: I only wrote the route for illustration. The point is that if I visit a blog post and then move the mouse to another menu item, the url will be /blog/history or /blog/contact and I will get a 404 error page.

Comment: Start URLs in a link with `/` to start from the topmost folder of your server's "DocumentRoot". `<a href="/{{ $item->slug }}"...`. When you are inside the `/blog` folder, linking to `href="home"` will link to `/blog/home`, but linking to `href="/home"` would take you to `/home`. (For this to work your project should be served from the project folder, not some subfolder of your localhost)

Comment: Yes, I just noticed after typing the comment that the url doesn't include the / sign. Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).